# { "detail": "Not found." }

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls

views

```
class Check(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Log.objects.all().order_by('-date_to_recived')
    serializer_class = LogSerializer
    permission_classes = [OwnerPermission]

def get_queryset(self):
    date = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    user = self.request.user
    return Log.objects.filter(product__owner = user,date_to_recived=date)
```

urls

```
 path('check/<str:pk>',Check.as_view(),name='check'),
```

hello, i try to recive multiple objects with my input(date). but i get this

[image]

Comment: The `RetrieveAPIView` will call the `get_object` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with a `ListAPIView`:

```
class CheckView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Log.objects.all().order_by('-date_to_recived')
    serializer_class = LogSerializer
    permission_classes = [OwnerPermission]

def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(
        product__owner=self.request.user,
        date_to_recived=self.kwargs['pk']
    )
```

That being said, it is a bit odd to filter on a `DateTimeField`, since a millisecond can make a difference whether or not to retrieve an object. Often one filters on the `__date` of the `DateTimeField`.

I would also suggest that your rename `Check` to `CheckView`, since that makes it more clear that this is a view, not a model.